# GitHub Action not creating publish folder and not updating DLLs

Tags: iis, github-actions, cicd

I have successfully built the pipeline in GitHub actions, which is also building successfully on each push in the master branch. But these above commands are not making publish folder and neither can I get DLLs. It means this is working fine but my code is not getting updated on the success build.

```yaml
name: ASP.NET Core Web API Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x  # or the version you're using

    - name: Build and publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish

    - name: Stop IIS Website
      run: |
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        Stop-WebSite -Name "practicecicdgithub" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    - name: Deploy to IIS
      run: |
        $publishFolder = "${{ github.workspace }}/publish"
        $siteName = "practicecicdgithub"
        $destinationFolder = "D:\PublishPracticeAPIs"

        # Copy published files to the target folder
        Copy-Item -Path $publishFolder -Destination $destinationFolder -Recurse -Force

        # Import the WebAdministration module
        Import-Module WebAdministration

          # Create a new website
          New-WebApplication -Name $siteName -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath
          $destinationFolder
    - name: Recycle application pool
      run: |
         $appPoolName = "DefaultAppPool"  # Replace with the name of your application pool
         Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Import-Module WebAdministration; Restart-WebAppPool -Name
        $args[0] } -ArgumentList $appPoolName
```

I have already verified the build output and copied files this is giving me the path that I am unable to find in my local system. I see that it is not creating any folder of the publish dlls.
It shows me this directory which is not even available in my system but getting published successfully.

Directory: D:\a\PracticeCICDGithub\PracticeCICDGithub\publish

[image]

Comment: You expect the GitHub Actions workflow's output to be present on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, I am publishing my site on local IIS i.e. in my system

Comment: Your local machine and the GHA hosted runner are different machines. If your local machine is on the internet (available publicly e.g. via SSH) then you can configure your workflow to publish those changes to that machine. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Sure, no worries. For now, you can build those DLLs via GHA workflow and then upload those as artifacts. Then, you can manually download those and use wherever needed. See https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact for more details.